# Thevenin problem

Tags: thevenin

Trying to find Rth and Vth but the placement of the resistors and the voltage sources is causing me some issues. Can someone help put me on the right track?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please provide an attempt at a solution. We expect you to put forth a substantial effort to solve this yourself and **show all of your work**. Explain what you mean by **causing me some issues**. Ask **specific** questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework and does not show what attempts poster has made at solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little helping hand: -

[image]

Do you see what I've done to simplify the circuit?

Use your eyes and your brain and redraw the circuit to make things simpler.

<sub>Finding Rth does not involve voltage sources by the way.</sub>

Comment: I hope he wasn’t offended by your unintended remark  “use your brain” ;)